# fix the buttons below tables which will be shown or hidden

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have buttons in my form and above it I have tables that I will set them to block and not blocking(Javascript) 
when I click the link the relative table will show the content my problem is that by clicking the links the position of buttons will change I want them to be fixed what should I do?
(I have 2 form tags in a page this form is second one)
Thanks in Advance

```
<form name="ruleSaveSettingForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return applySave();">
<input type="hidden" name="rule_id">
<input type="hidden" name="rule_value">
<input type="hidden" name="openerhref">
<table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td class="tdaction"> <input type="submit" id="Save" value="Save" class="but"></td>
<td class="tdaction"> <input type="button" id="Reset" value="Reset" class="but" onclick="resetForm();return false;"></td>
<td class="tdaction"> <input type="button" id="Close" value="Close" class="but" onclick="window.close();"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you put the buttons at the top instead?  That would seem like a simple answer.

Comment: the format of my buttons in whole pages are below them I am not allowed to do it I tried to put a table with a fixed width(empty table) but again nothing changed:"(

Comment: I need some entity which I don't know to set the position then it will not change but I don't know how?

Comment: here's a hint: forget using tables. This is so 1998. Use divs and CSS your life will be so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

1. Its better to move the buttons out of the out of the table , if its
   placed inside it.
2. Move your table to a div and give it the style
   property

```
min-height:50px;
```

This will remain the height of the div to 50 px even if the table is made hidden using java script.

Hope this will solve ur problem

Comment: Thank you would you please tell it more clear? in where i should use dive exactly?you mean i should erase the table and instead put the div?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style='min-height:150px;' id='yourID'>
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data1</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data1</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data1</td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>button1</td>
            <td>button2</td>
            <td>button3</td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In the above sample , you need to place the buttons in  anew div.You are free to use div or table.

Comment: div didn't work for me I tried exactly what you have said be aware that my tables are not static they are dynamic i click one of them another one will close the position again is changing